# Get list of data and log files from detached SQL Server .mdf file

Tags: sql-server, smo

Given a detached SQL Server Primary Data File (`.mdf`) how can you get the list of data and log files that exist inside that file? The goal is to use the `Server.AttachDatabase` SMO method to attach the database. But the database may have multiple data and/or log files so I need to get the list in order to add them to the `StringCollection` parameter of the method.

What I need is the equivalent of `select * from sys.files` for a detached mdf. SQL Server Management Studio does this when you use it to manually attach a database so I know it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a single MDF file, if there are other MDF files I don't think the MDF file can tell you that directly.

And you can always *try* to attach an MDF file without a log file by using the [`CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) option.

In SMO you can do this using the [`AttachDatabase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.attachdatabase) method specifying `RebuildLog` for [`AttachOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.attachoptions).

Of course this all assumes the .mdf file is healthy - it will only be usable if it was cleanly detached.

Management Studio probably has some proprietary way of reading the file headers, but these aren't documented and you're not going to be able see what SSMS is doing using Profiler or the like.

If you are typically creating .mdf files for distribution of some kind, I really strongly recommend using backup/restore instead. You can learn a lot more about a .BAK file and the data/log files its database represents, using documented and public methods such as [`RESTORE FILELISTONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Comment: This is for migration of hundreds of DB's using a PS script. I didn't want to have to store the datafile (secondary) and logfile locations, names, etc.  before I detach.  Looks like that is the way to go though. Basically what I am trying to create is a script that will, given a folder full of .mdf, .ndf, .ldf, buile the SMO AttachDatabase stringcollection with the files for that db.

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured this one out.  The undocumented command DBCC checkprimaryfile(N'blah.mdf',3) gives the info needed.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to find it, but in SMO, you use EnumDetachedLogFiles and EnumDetachedLogFiles.

```
# PowerShell
$servername = "sqlserver\instance"
$mdf = "S:\DATA\mydb.mdf"

[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO")
$filestructure = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $servername

# Here you can automatically determine the database name, or set it manually
$dbname = ($server.DetachedDatabaseInfo($mdf) | Where { $_.Property -eq "Database name" }).Value

foreach    ($file in $server.EnumDetachedDatabaseFiles($mdf)) {
    $null = $filestructure.add($file)
}

foreach ($file in $server.EnumDetachedLogFiles($mdf)) {
    $null = $filestructure.add($file)
}
```

[Enumerate detached database file structures](https://blog.netnerds.net/2015/01/enumerate-file-structure-within-detached-mdf-database-file-using-smo/)

[SMO Attach/Detach Recipes](https://blog.netnerds.net/smo-recipes/detach-attach/)